# Error in android service class

Tags: android, android-service

I am getting the following error in service class. What is the issue here ?

Error:(17, 8) error: NotificationService is not abstract and does not override abstract method onBind(Intent) in Service

This is my code :

```
package works.viswajith.birthdayreminder;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;


import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by Viswajith on 6/17/2015.
 */
public class NotificationService extends Service {

   DBHelper db;
   private Cursor cur;
   private Calendar cal;
   private int d,m,y;
   private String[] temp;
   private NotificationManager nm;
   int i=0;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        db=new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        cur=db.getDetails();
        cal= Calendar.getInstance();
        d=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        m=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        y=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        for(i=0;i<db.getCount();i++)
        {
           temp=cur.getString(2).split("/");
            if(Integer.parseInt(temp[0])==d)
            {

                NotificationCompat.Builder mbuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                mbuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.happy);
                mbuilder.setContentTitle("Happy B'day "+cur.getString(0));
                mbuilder.setContentText("Today is "+cur.getString(0)+"'s B'day , Wish him ..");
                nm=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                nm.notify(100,mbuilder.build());


            }

            cur.moveToNext();

        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think anything can be added to the error message you have. `Service`, that you override, has an abstract method `onBind`. Since your class is not abstract, you can't have abstract methods. Therefore, you need to implement the abstract method. I tried, but I really feel this is just paraphrasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error has explained it to you perfectly clear: You have to override `onBind()` or otherwise make your service abstract.

This is how you should do it:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
   // Implement your logic here.
}
```

Comment: Glad it did! Kindly accept my answer if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you exactly what you need to do...

Because you are extending a service, you need to override the `onBind` method.

Add the following to your class:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
}
```

This method will be called when android binds to your services.